# TypeScript + Cucumber Issue : Error: function timed out after 10000 milliseconds

Tags: javascript, typescript, selenium-webdriver, cucumberjs

I am running cucumber selenium tests using TypeScript and facing following error :

> whilst trying to wait: Error: function timed out after 10000
>   milliseconds

Please find below my source code:

```
Then(/^I see the application Homepage$/, async () => {
    await browser.sleep(10000);
    expect(browser.getTitle()).to.eventually.equal('Application - Module Page');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got this sorted out, changing settings in conf.js was not getting picked however the code below in defineSupportCode worked :

```
defineSupportCode(function ({ registerHandler, registerListener, After, setDefaultTimeout }) {
 setDefaultTimeout(20 * 1000);
 let jsonReports = process.cwd() + "/reports/json";
 let htmlReports = process.cwd() + "/reports/html";
 let targetJson = jsonReports + "/cucumber_report.json";
```